# Instantaneous Center of Rotation of Skid-Steering Mobile Robot

Tags: mobile-robot, kinematics, wheeled-robot, forward-kinematics, motion

Is there a instantaneous center of rotation (ICR) for 4-wheeled skid steering mobile robot (such as Husky , Pioneer 3-AT) if the center of mass is located at the geometric center of the robot? What if it is not located at the geometric center of the robot?

Answer (score 1):

If the context is differential drive calculations, the robot's z-axis center-of-rotation has nothing to do with the robot's mass.